# QTKit does not enumerate my USB- and virtual cams in 64Bit mode. Is there a workaround?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, 64-bit, quicktime, qtkit

I have a problem with Quicktime, that means, QTKit. A long time ago I wrote an app, which is using camera devices on Mac OS X. The user could select the camera using a popup box. I populated the device list into a popup box so the user could choose his preferred camera. Now I migrated to 64Bit code. And everything works fine with iSight cam. Audio devices are listed properly, too (including virtual drivers like Soundflower). For my surprise all camera-devices are missing. And QTKit never enumerates the existing cameras. Is there a workaround or does someone know something about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. Haven't found a workaround other than keeping it 32bit. The Quicktime API mailing list has already discussed this [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/QuickTime-API/2011/Jul/msg00025.html) basically stating that the camera device (your camera device) is a Quicktime Component and Quicktime Components are only supported with Quicktime 7 not Quicktime X if I understood this correctly.

So to put it bluntly: Quicktime Components are not supported in 64bit, for whatever reason I don't understand.

**Update:** another discussion on the quicktime-api-lists also covers this topic [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/Az8ST0TRmQx6qQi1utKw). Search for vdig in the discussion and you'll find statements on the whole 32bit vs. 64bit complications:

> Apple has never updated or replaced the VDIG/ SG / QuickTime Component
>   API to a 64 bit architecture and your VDIG will never show up as a
>   selectable device under 64 Bit. So your VDIG is screwed, just like
>   every other Mac 3rd party QT component developer is.

Also, the term QTKitServer pops up, which seems undocumented but is used by Quicktime X in 64bit mode to play movies in 32bit by using Quicktime components.

Maybe QTKitServer is the key?